# SoapExceptions error: The property 'Name' is read-only and cannot be modified or deleted. (SSRS)

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have created a Windows Application based UI using C# to enable users to manage the items of the Reporting Server. One of the functionalities I have implemented was to right-click on the name of the folder (in the UI TreeView hierarchy) and choose the 'Rename' option from the menu, which will then call the ReportingServices2005.SetProperties function. I added the Property of the "Name" and "Value" to the array and passed that as a parameter in this function. And I get a lengthy error message, but it's really only saying:

*System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapExceptions: The property 'Name' is **read-only** and cannot be modified or deleted -->
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReadOnlyPropertyException: ...*

I've set the MessageBox.Show() within the code to display *TreeView*.**SelectedNodes.Nodes.IsReadOnly** and it shows 'False'. So I don't think anything's set up to be read-only. I could also go to the Reporting Manager itself and rename there with no problem. Is the 'Name' one of the properties that I am not going to be able to edit from the User Interface application? Other properties such as Hidden or Description were editable. I appreciate your replies in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you cannot rename this property during runtime, is because the value is actually stored in your RDLC file.  In order to actually modify this value, you would need to modify the RDLC file in memory - and reload it in your reportViewer control.